# Add Fonts in Quill Editor - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, quill

I am having difficulty adding fonts to my quill editor in my angular application. It appears that I need to import the formats/font and whitelist the fonts that I want to use in my editor, but nothing I do is adding the fonts currently. Please see the code below and let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="text-area">
    <quill-editor 
    [styles]="quill_styles" 
    [modules]="modules"
    [(ngModel)]="htmlContent"
    placeholder="Hello World"
    ></quill-editor>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter';
import { EditorChangeContent, EditorChangeSelection } from 'ngx-quill'

// const Font = Quill.import('formats/font') // Thought this would work
// Font.whitelist = ['sofia'] // Thought this would work
Quill.register('modules/blotFormatter', BlotFormatter);
// Quill.register(Font,true) // Thought this would work

export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
constructor( //Irrelevant ) {} 

  toolbarOptions = [
    'bold','italic', 'underline', 'strike',
    {'font': ['sofia']},
    { 'size': [] },
    { 'color': [] },
    { 'background': [] },
    'link','image', 'video', 'formula',
    { 'script': 'super' }, { 'script': 'sub' },
    'clean'
  ]

  modules = {
    toolbar: [this.toolbarOptions],
    blotFormatter: {},
  }

  quill_styles = {
    'height':'50vh'
  }
}
```